# xslt transform using second xml document

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have an xml data file that will contain a large number of repeating fields, each which are associated to about 10 unique facility names, like this:

```
<Dailyreport>
<msg>
<msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
<facility>North</facility>
<ispass>0</ispass>
</msg>
<msg>
<msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdata>
<facility>South</facility>
<ispass>1</ispass>
</msg>
</Dailyreport>
```

I have an XSL stylesheet version 1.0 that is working where I can obtain the count of occurrences by facility, which looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" rules="all" border="1">

<xsl:if test="Dailyreport//msg[facility='North']">
<tr><td>North Building:</td></tr>
<tr><td>Total:<xsl:value-of select="count(Dailyreport/msg[facility='North'])"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Pass:<xsl:value-of select="count(Dailyreport/msg[facility='North' and ispass='1'])"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Fail:<xsl:value-of select="count(DailyELRreport/msg[facility='North' and ispass='0'])"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>-------------------</td></tr>
<tr><td> 
</td></tr>
</xsl:if>
</table>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, in order to get counts for all of the possible facilities, I have to repeat the (xsl:if test) section, with each of the facility names.

I would like to see if I can locate the facility names in a second xml data file and use the document() function to iterate through them by possibly loading them into a global parameter, and then using a call-template function to repeatedly call one single (xsl:if test) section.  And have it use the parameter value instead of a fixed facility name....something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="Dailyreport//msg[facility=$sender]">
```

Everything I've tried has failed.
Wondering if anyone can help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given these two XML documents:

**facilities.xml**

```
<facilities>
    <facility code="North">North Building</facility>
    <facility code="South">South Building</facility>
</facilities>
```

**XML (this is the document processed by XSLT)**

```
<Dailyreport>
   <msg>
    <msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
    <facility>North</facility>
    <ispass>1</ispass>
  </msg>
  <msg>
    <msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
    <facility>North</facility>
    <ispass>1</ispass>
  </msg>
 <msg>
    <msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
    <facility>North</facility>
    <ispass>0</ispass>
  </msg>
  <msg>
    <msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
    <facility>South</facility>
    <ispass>0</ispass>
  </msg>
  <msg>
    <msgdate>05/27/2015</msgdate>
    <facility>South</facility>
    <ispass>0</ispass>
  </msg>
</Dailyreport>
```

the folowing stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="msg" match="msg" use="facility" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="report" select="." />
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="document('facilities.xml')/facilities/facility">
            <tr>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:variable name="code" select="@code" />
            <!-- switch context back to XML document -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$report">
                <xsl:variable name="messages" select="key('msg', $code)" />
                <tr>
                    <td>Total:<xsl:value-of select="count($messages)"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pass:<xsl:value-of select="count($messages[ispass='1'])"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fail:<xsl:value-of select="count($messages[ispass='0'])"/></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>North Building</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Total:3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Pass:2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Fail:1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>South Building</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Total:2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Pass:0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Fail:2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Sorry....I don't seem to have any object on the page designating the action of closing the question.  How do I do that?

Comment: I don't believe I need to do anymore actions.   At least I can't see any.  I can't vote as I don't have reps.  And I checked the green check.